# Why i can't select multiple columns with "$System.TMSCHEMA_TABLES"?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssas, dax

I'm new to SQL Server and I'm trying to get a information about all the tables in SSAS solution via using this DMV query in DAX Studio and it's working like a charm and give all the information.

```
select * from $System.TMSCHEMA_TABLES
```

But when I'm trying to get information about specific column by using the following command, I get errors.

```
select ID, NAME, MODIFIED_DATE from $System.TMSCHEMA_TABLES
```

The partitions part `$System.TMSCHEMA_PARTITIONS` is working nicely. Eventually I want to achieve something like this:

```
Select t2.Name,t1.ModifiedTime,t1.RefreshedTime 
from 
$System.TMSCHEMA_PARTITIONS t1 
Inner join
$System.TMSCHEMA_TABLES t2 ON t1.TableID = t2.ID
```

Comment: a) Always post errors you receive. b) Try enclosing column names in square brackets (`[ID], [Name]` and so on).

Answer (score 2):

These are DMVs NOT SQL queries, they are actually written in [MDX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/multidimensional-models/mdx/mdx-query-fundamentals-analysis-services) so you cannot select/join as you normally would in a SQL query.

This:

```
select  [ID], 
        [NAME],      
        [ModifiedTime]
from    $System.TMSCHEMA_TABLES
```

will work

But, if you want to join results on an ID you will have to find another solution.

Answer (score 0):

The other alternative Way is on Database Instance Crete Linked server with SSAS Instance.
Use openrowset on sql to get the Info from DMV Query from SSAS and load the same into a temp table and use this in subsequent joins.

Refernce:

https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/reporting-services-read-data-from-ssas-and-sql-server-in-one-dataset